# How to insert silence into an audio file with programming?

Tags: audio

I have different audio files those are one hour long and I want to insert silence with a same predefined positions and length into all of these files. Is there any software which is capable of doing this job? Otherwise I should edit audio files separately which will take a lot of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "inserting silence" you mean to pad the file with silence, and thereby changing the duration of the track, I'd use SoX:

```
# example file
sox -n -r 44100 -b 16 before.wav synth 20 brownnoise

# pads with 5 seconds of silence at the 2 seconds mark    
sox before.wav after-pad.wav pad 5@2
```

If by "inserting silence" you mean to mute a section of the file, and thereby keeping duration the same, I'd use FFmpeg:

```
# example file
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "anoisesrc=d=20:c=brown:r=44100:a=0.5" before.wav

# sets volume to zero between the 2 and 5 second marks
ffmpeg -i before.wav -af "volume=enable='between(t,2,5)':volume=0" after-mute.wav
```

To batch process files, move to a folder containing the files you want to process (assumes WAV) and run either

```
files="*.wav"
for f in $files
do
  sox "$f" "${f%.*}-pad.wav" pad 5@2
done
```

or

```
files="*.wav"
for f in $files
do
  ffmpeg -i "$f" -af "volume=enable='between(t,2,7)':volume=0" "${f%.*}-mute.wav"
done
```

Comment: Excellent! I was looking for exactly this kind of software. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend Audacity.  It is free and there is great [documentation](http://manual.audacityteam.org/).  Here is a [how-to document](http://www.howtogeek.com/57571/how-to-quickly-edit-multiple-files-in-audacity/) on editing multiple files with Audacity's "chain" feature.

Comment: I have searched Audacity, but could not find this function. Anyway, AkselA's answer is a decent solution for my problem.

Comment: Audacity is nice, but not a solution for this question.